# Is $D(f)$ of quasi-affine variety open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here $k$ is a fixed algebraically closed field. Let $X$ be an affine algebraic variety (over $k$), and $U\subseteq X$ is its open subset (quasi-affine variety). Then, is the subset
$$
D(f) := \{p\in U \ |\ f(p)\neq 0\}
$$
for a regular function $f\in\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ open in $U$?

Here the regular functions $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U) = \bigcap_{p\in U}k[X]_{I(p)}$ is a sub $k$-algebra of $k(X)$(the rational functions on $X$, which is the fractional field of the coordinate ring $k[X]$. ).

I need this lemma to show that regular map between quasi-affine varieties is continuous. I have already proven that, in affine variety, $D(f)$ is isomorphic to some affine variety. (The definition of regular map between quasi-affine varieties : $\varphi: U\to V$ is regular if composition with projection $U\to \mathbb{A}^1$ is in $\mathcal{O}_{U}(U)$.)